# Prove the inequality using simple induction.

Tags: summation, induction, contest-math, real-numbers

I was solving this question:

> Let $A_1,A_2,A_3\cdots A_n$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $A_{i+j} \leq A_i + A_j ,\forall i, j \in\mathbb{N}$.
> Prove that $A_1 + \frac{A_2}2 + \frac{A_3}{3} +\cdots + \frac{A_n}n \geq A_n$.

I was able to prove that $A_1 \geq \frac{A_n}n$ for all $n$ being natural using induction. But after that I am unable to use this fact to prove the required statement.

I don't think that from given inequality, any other inequality will actually prove to be useful, so what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for edit. I didn't know how to write like this in math notations.Sorry

Comment: Let $n=2$. If $A_1=1$ and $A_2=30$ then $A_1+\frac{1}{2}A_2\geq A_2$. But this is the same as $1+\frac{1}{2}30\geq 30$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that for any $n$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}i \ge a_n $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960602/prove-that-for-any-n-we-have-sum-i-1n-fraca-ii-ge-a-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1$ it's true.

Let $a_1+\frac{a_2}{2}+...+\frac{a_n}{n}\geq a_n$ for $n\in\{1,2,...,n\}$.

After summing of these $n$ inequalities we obtain:
$$na_1+(n-1)\frac{a_2}{2}+...+\frac{a_n}{n}\geq a_1+a_2+...+a_n,$$ which gives
$$na_1+a_1+(n-1)\frac{a_2}{2}+a_2+...+\frac{a_n}{n}+a_n\geq$$
$$\geq(a_1+a_n)+(a_2+a_{n-1})+...+(a_n+a_1)\geq na_{n+1},$$ which gives
$$(n+1)\left(a_1+\frac{a_2}{2}+...+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)\geq na_{n+1}$$ or
$$a_1+\frac{a_2}{2}+...+\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\geq\frac{na_{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}$$ or
$$a_1+\frac{a_2}{2}+...+\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\geq a_{n+1}$$ and we are done by induction.

Comment: There was nothing to end. Just one more line to add.I feel like an idiot.But,Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Combat Miners  You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: So how do you end it?

Comment: @lockedscope I added something. See now.